# WCF Test Client Won't Refresh

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am having a very frustrating problem with the WCF test client. When I build my WCF service locally and debug I am able to test it in the test client app. However, when I make a change, sometimes even completely removing a service method, it absolutely will not refresh. It's like it's caching a copy of the service somewhere. I have tried everything, closing and re-opening the test client, VS, etc....

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually right clicking on the service reference and selecting Update Reference?

It won't automatically update your service proxy...you have to tell it to go back out and check for changes.

Comment: Yes I am. This is really strange.

Comment: How did you reference the service initially?

Comment: Debug in VS, launch wcftest, then add a service reference using something like http://localhost:12345/MyService.svc

Comment: We've run into a similar issue. Probably, there's a cache somewhere... I even can step through my newly minted assembly but the watch values of variables will reflect the reality that a cache is being used (I can set one to a new value, compile, copy to GAC, and run debug, but when I run a watch on the value it shows the old value even though I'm stepping through the code with the new value.)